# What kind of project type is this?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, portable-class-library, .net-standard

**Context**

I installed a solution template (Exrin Mobile App) and there are project types inside what displayed in Solution Explorer as ...(Portable) but when I go to project /Properties/Library in the Target setting I see .NET Standard instead of the usual multiple targets and [Change] button to select with checkboxes.

**Question**

So it seems to be a hybrid, neither PCL Library, neither .NET Standard Library. Is this a some hack in the .csproj file, or how can I create such kind of project with the VS 2017.3 built in project templates?

(Please note: The question is not about what is .NET Standard, and why it is the recommended over PCL)

[image]

[image]

**instead of the 'normal' PCL which target used to be displayed as:**

[image]

Comment: I don't know the built-in project type. But I think you can just copy the csproj file and use that as a template.

Comment: Yes, I've already did it. My question is not a practical question, just would like to understand what kind of animal it is...

Comment: What are the `ProjectTypeGuids` values in the `.csproj`?

Comment: <ProjectTypeGuids>{786C830F-07A1-408B-BD7F-6EE04809D6DB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>

Comment: 786C830F.... is a normal Portable Class Library and a FA‌​E04EC0.... is the C# language, so a C# PCL-based project. So from your screen shot it appears to be a PCL project that was *converted* to a NetStd one thus the old style `.csproj` but one with a `project.json` vs. a `project.config`. Welcome to the strange land of hybrid NetStd projects.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a normal portable class library project which has been edited to target .NET Standard. This format should work in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and above, though it never was publicly announced or used in templates since it was primarily a hacky way to be able to build .NET Standard and .NET Core projects with MSBuild instead of `project.json` based tooling.

Since this is no longer the way .NET Core and .NET Standard projects are supposed to be built, I recommend not trying to create a similar project. This also relies on NuGet support for `project.json` based dependencies which is about to be removed from NuGet after UWP switches to `PackageReference` elements inside the csproj from `project.json`.

You can read about this type of project in the CoreFX document [Using MSBuild to build .NET Core projects](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/f77a66355ca596276b5905575a6976e925ef046d/Documentation/project-docs/target-dotnetcore-with-msbuild.md) (this was written before the .NET Core SDK 1.0 based on MSBuild tooling was released, the document is about .NET Core applications but it works similarly for .NET Standard)

Comment: Many thanks for the details. I have a bad feeling, because this is a green field start of an innovative project, and I spent time to have a good and future pointing, and it turns out that the project type is kinda not that direction. Well, so much confusing parallel things, just the deal with NuGet is three kind, the packages.config, project.json along with .csproj, PackageReference inside .csproj, and more? Then the many different project types, PCL, etc then the targets... Any recommendation what project type / template to use libraries what are common code for Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: Xamarin.Forms (and UWP) is about to add .NET Standard support that can be used with the new .NET Standard project types in VS 2017 https://blog.xamarin.com/building-xamarin-forms-apps-net-standard/